# How to extract urls from text file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files

I have a text file full of URLs and text i want to extract URLs that start with

```
thumbnailUrl\": \
```

I used this code

```
def get_net_target(page):
    start_link=page.find("thumbnailUrl")
    start_quote=page.find('"',start_link)
    end_quote=page.find('"',start_quote+1)
    url=page[start_quote+1:end_quote]
    print url

my_file = open("data.txt")
page = my_file.read()

print(get_net_target(page))
```

I want output like this

```
https://tse3.mm.bing.net///th?id=OIP.Mcbb568859281f5bc7a7f64d8c58d4895H1&pid=Api\
https:\\/\\/tse1.mm.bing.net\\/th?id=OIP.M7ff1f4e880bac2c244c0b6a286cee669o2&pid=Api\
```

....

but I get only:

```
None
```

**Few lines of data are...**

```
webSearchUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=RUc0BARkL2P78A5CI7XPWqhCYAA2XaQLP-fHGdfODEY&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fimages%2fsearch%3fview%3ddetailv2%26FORM%3dOIIRPO%26q%3dshoaibmalik%26id%3d97C5A1ECB43BCDC1B5739F49555CE0C75CEDF83F%26simid%3d607996336242885612&p=DevEx,5006.1\", \"thumbnailUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/tse2.mm.bing.net\\/th?id=OIP.Me19820ab68b4bcc7ec82756b2b5ecffbo1&pid=Api\", \"datePublished\": \"2011-07-08T12:00:00\", \"contentUrl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=gA9S9qCIF1jvD5yA4V9VOqfrJUxdW2_wyacSDR15Yc8&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fwww.forumpakistan.com%2fimages%2fcelebrity-profiles%2fShoaib-Malik-1.jpg&p=DevEx,5008.1\", \"hostPageUrl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=IODAmtxi3pYzDGhiJcJgCv0fWHEq8hlJauGxRW5o2c4&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fok-khan.blogspot.com%2f2011%2f07%2fshoaib-malik.html&p=DevEx,5007.1\", \"contentSize\": \"48445 B\", \"encodingFormat\": \"jpeg\", \"hostPageDisplayUrl\": \"ok-khan.blogspot.com\\/2011\\/07\\/shoaib-malik.html\", \"width\": 500, \"height\": 647, \"thumbnail\": {\"width\": 231, \"height\": 300}, \"imageInsightsToken\": \"ccid_4Zggq2i0*mid_97C5A1ECB43BCDC1B5739F49555CE0C75CEDF83F*simid_607996336242885612\", \"imageId\": \"97C5A1ECB43BCDC1B5739F49555CE0C75CEDF83F\", \"accentColor\": \"3A6491\"}, {\"name\": \"Pakistani Crickert Player: Shoaib Malik\", \"webSearchUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=4qc04BUbtNDwiCHco5m3IY_YFqKVaY2q8ZWhX-DvFQs&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fimages%2fsearch%3fview%3ddetailv2%26FORM%3dOIIRPO%26q%3dshoaibmalik%26id%3dF690295FD18526BA8225367169A0664405923A09%26simid%3d608039315980946676&p=DevEx,5012.1\", \"thumbnailUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/tse3.mm.bing.net\\/th?id=OIP.Mcbb568859281f5bc7a7f64d8c58d4895H1&pid=Api\", \"datePublished\": \"2012-12-24T12:00:00\", \"contentUrl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=9psh5pXKn2R_2Zn4-iMzpjDFePVuLSNVJhbVjf2uTI0&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fi1.tribune.com.pk%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2010%2f10%2fshoaib-malik-640x480.jpg&p=DevEx,5014.1\", \"hostPageUrl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=-cUvEUoDmZ1OAI-PVQc4MOfS-ELdt5Im521SJ2ZP4j8&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fpakistanicricketplayr44410.blogspot.com%2f2012%2f12%2fshoaib-malik.html&p=DevEx,5013.1\", \"contentSize\": \"51986 B\", \"encodingFormat\": \"jpeg\", \"hostPageDisplayUrl\": \"pakistanicricketplayr44410.blogspot.com\\/2012\\/12\\/shoaib-malik.html\", \"width\": 640, \"height\": 480, \"thumbnail\": {\"width\": 300, \"height\": 225}, \"imageInsightsToken\": \"ccid_y7VohZKB*mid_F690295FD18526BA8225367169A0664405923A09*simid_608039315980946676\", \"imageId\": \"F690295FD18526BA8225367169A0664405923A09\", \"accentColor\": \"98AE1D\"}, {\"name\": \"Pakistani Cricket Players: Shoaib Malik\", \"webSearchUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=n2Lkz5bg7h-AgbmZE4SnL-_AFBcCgc-_vaiVeAuC84s&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fimages%2fsearch%3fview%3ddetailv2%26FORM%3dOIIRPO%26q%3dshoaibmalik%26id%3d320A83F8A63DED3BD4B4EF926CAA3BE901F9DEA2%26simid%3d608028569977424814&p=DevEx,5018.1\", \"thumbnailUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/tse3.mm.bing.net\\/th?id=OIP.Mb6ca65eda578c80e71f4c3b3193c5b67H1&pid=Api\", \"datePublished\": \"2011-04-17T12:00:00\", \"contentUrl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=TwpcQHy-RdAJUStMisg6zBtjt_j60EStRFRAJS1D69Q&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fimages.teamtalk.com%2f08%2f10%2f800x600%2fShoaib-Malik_1264846.jpg&p=DevEx,5020.1\", \"hostPageUrl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=xICbhyFdmUBblBavcA3pXPdpbOa-1bJuBvP5H6Z0kms&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fcricketplayerspk.blogspot.com%2f2011%2f04%2fshoaib-malik.html&p=DevEx,5019.1\", \"contentSize\": \"51243 B\", \"encodingFormat\": \"jpeg\", \"hostPageDisplayUrl\": \"cricketplayerspk.blogspot.com\\/2011\\/04\\/shoaib-malik.html\", \"width\": 800, \"height\": 600, \"thumbnail\": {\"width\": 300, \"height\": 225}, \"imageInsightsToken\": \"ccid_tspl7aV4*mid_320A83F8A63DED3BD4B4EF926CAA3BE901F9DEA2*simid_608028569977424814\", \"imageId\": \"320A83F8A63DED3BD4B4EF926CAA3BE901F9DEA2\", \"accentColor\": \"416838\"}, {\"name\": \"Shoaib Malik in line for Test comeback after 5 years - Sports\", \"webSearchUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=7CIa0gvwncEquihLMmMIvtYAAUYZutf8EQr57d8EDO0&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fimages%2fsearch%3fview%3ddetailv2%26FORM%3dOIIRPO%26q%3dshoaibmalik%26id%3d8045A5C7203C2203C8238D9E00905FCB328BD4D9%26simid%3d608033376034882300&p=DevEx,5024.1\", \"thumbnailUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/tse2.mm.bing.net\\/th?id=OIP.M65fe5bf16283dc466e93650fbaef1205o1&pid=Api\", \"datePublished\": \"2015-10-06T04:07:00\", \"contentUrl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=F2RLPPSfrErnxq7OZt_3mbKbvpJITet7f_kGd90aKlg&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fimages.mid-day.com%2fimages%2f2015%2foct%2f6Shoaib-Malik-1.jpg&p=DevEx,5026.1\", \"hostPageUrl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=3V02TER99J6fm2eshh_cv4NCdJELV1DpI1pOmALtDMQ&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mid-day.com%2farticles%2fshoaib-malik-in-line-for-test-comeback-after-5-years%2f16586181&p=DevEx,5025.1\", \"contentSize\": \"119997 B\", \"encodingFormat\": \"jpeg\", \"hostPageDisplayUrl\": \"www.mid-day.com\\/articles\\/shoaib-malik-in-line-for-test-comeback...\", \"width\": 670, \"height\": 746, \"thumbnail\": {\"width\": 269, \"height\": 300}, \"imageInsightsToken\": \"ccid_Zf5b8WKD*mid_8045A5C7203C2203C8238D9E00905FCB328BD4D9*simid_608033376034882300\", \"imageId\": \"8045A5C7203C2203C8238D9E00905FCB328BD4D9\", \"accentColor\": \"304987\"}, {\"name\": \"Gallery > Cricketers > Shoaib Malik > Shoaib Malik high quality! Free ...\", \"webSearchUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=A9FD1ucKtYszoNQZ2KEhYMvgMwvJ6AA5d-DFInyr9I4&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fimages%2fsearch%3fview%3ddetailv2%26FORM%3dOIIRPO%26q%3dshoaibmalik%26id%3dB7AD00B57D67FD1664C7BBA404FF6E2679019517%26simid%3d608007657767896024&p=DevEx,5030.1\", \"thumbnailUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/tse3.mm.bing.net\\/th?id=OIP.M5d9fb4d528228cb5c8b9748bff10365bo1&pid=Api\", \"datePublished\": \"2013-05-18T00:44:00\", \"contentUrl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/cr?IG=4588890DDF1744A79DAEC3DB4C5C87D0&CID=3C16AFB87BB96F70283EA5B77A886E24&rd=1&h=7jwPNSK-kjHNAXQmqBqznMWCB3u4YPz0uHDFoJizw1U&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fpak101.com%2fgallery%2fCricketers%2fShoaib_Malik%2f2011%2f9%2f22%2fShoaib_Malik_Picture_9_xmnqf.jpg&p=DevEx,5032.1\", \"hostPageUrl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\
```

Comment: please reformat your code and check your indentation

Comment: Please supply a few lines of your data file that fail, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: As long we do not know how the input looks like nobody can verify your code. Please paste some example lines of your data.txt

Comment: please check my code and data now and give suitable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code demonstrates two approaches. The first parallels your and the second shows an easier way involving the use of regular expressions.

It's worth learning the first way but the trick is to keep your place in the string that you're parsing.

```
data = '''webSearchUrl\": \"https:\\/\\/w ... p:\\/\\/www.bing.com"'''
data = data.replace ('\/', '/')

print ('Using roughly your approach ...')

start = 0
while True:
    p = data[start:].find('thumbnailUrl')
    if p == -1: break
    q = data[start+p+12:].find('http')
    r = data[start+p+q+12:].find('"')
    print (data[start+p+q+12:start+p+q+r+12])
    start = start+p+q+r+12

print ('Using a regular expression ...')

from re import compile

thumbNailRE = compile(r'thumbnailUrl":\s+"([^"]+)')
for match in thumbNailRE.findall(data):
    print (match)
```

Outputs are identical:

```
Using roughly your approach ...
https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Me19820ab68b4bcc7ec82756b2b5ecffbo1&pid=Api
https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Mcbb568859281f5bc7a7f64d8c58d4895H1&pid=Api
https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Mb6ca65eda578c80e71f4c3b3193c5b67H1&pid=Api
https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M65fe5bf16283dc466e93650fbaef1205o1&pid=Api
https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M5d9fb4d528228cb5c8b9748bff10365bo1&pid=Api
Using a regular expression ...
https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Me19820ab68b4bcc7ec82756b2b5ecffbo1&pid=Api
https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Mcbb568859281f5bc7a7f64d8c58d4895H1&pid=Api
https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Mb6ca65eda578c80e71f4c3b3193c5b67H1&pid=Api
https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M65fe5bf16283dc466e93650fbaef1205o1&pid=Api
https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M5d9fb4d528228cb5c8b9748bff10365bo1&pid=Api
```